# FreeBSD jails mkstemp failed

Tags: freebsd, jail, mkstemp

I'm trying to install some stuff in my jails with this set up:
I have make my own flavor of jails by following this howto: [FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/39196/)
Everything worked fine for me so far, I have mounted /usr/ports with fstab to the jail, started the jail and entered it. But inside the jail I can't use make.

E.g.:

```
/usr/ports/www/nginx # make install clean
mktemp: mkstemp failed on /root/tmp/portoptions.bgGFZA6E: No such
file or directory
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/www/nginx
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/www/nginx
```

I'm some kind of confused by this error, as well as that there is no vi available etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of:

```
$ jls
$ jexec >>JID-No.<< su
```

you just have to run:

```
$ ezjail-admin console jailname
```

That solved it for me.